# How I can make a loading indicator with any color on android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-progressbar

I have a code want to user "Style.xml" as I show file content at the end. What I want to do is " The ProgressDailog Indicator to change its color which will be defined in Style.xml.... Simple.

public class SimpleProgressDialog extends Dialog {

```
public static SimpleProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message) {
    return show(context, title, message, false);
}

public static SimpleProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, false, null);
}

public static SimpleProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate, boolean cancelable) {
    return show(context, title, message, indeterminate, cancelable, null);
}

public static SimpleProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
        CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
        boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    SimpleProgressDialog dialog = new SimpleProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    /* The next line will add the ProgressBar to the dialog. */
    dialog.addContentView(new ProgressBar ( context , null ,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLargeInverse ), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    dialog.show();

    return dialog;
}

public SimpleProgressDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.NewDialog);
}
```

}

here is style. I want to modify just style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
  <!-- The style for the unit on the statistics activity. -->
<style name="NewDialog">
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What you're trying to do here is not clear. All I see in your XML file as far as color goes is the color "transparent" - could you try again to explain what you are wanting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I highly recommend putting you `ProgressBar` definition in its own XML layout. From there, you can easily apply the style by adding the attribute `style="@style/NewDialog"`

eg. create `progress.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/progress"
  style="@style/NewDialog"
  >
</ProgressBar>
```

And then in your code, do:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progres);
```

Comment: Sure. Can you please give me any example or link?

Comment: I try to do this. But no effect. but this is a way for this. Thanks for you time